# Boot freeze (black screen) when booting without power cable (ubuntu gnome 16.04 / Dell XPS15)

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, power-management, ubuntu-gnome

I noticed some errors since yesterday. When I plugged in my power cable, my laptop froze (couldn't do anything besides a hard reboot).

When I tried to boot without power cable, I get a black screen after I log in to my account (so I do see the login screen)

When I boot with power cable, no problem. When I unplug power cable, no problem. When I plug power cable in again... freeze

I have my laptop for just 7 days, it's a fresh install. I only installed "tlp" as that was recommanded for handling power management.

I have a 512 GB SSD, nvidia GTX 1050, no touchscreen

Oh and I have a dual boot with windows 10. Windows doesn't have any of these issues.

I really have no clue what the issue can be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/939764/how-do-i-sanity-check-my-acpi-tables

Answer (score 2):

I "fixed" it by replacing the nouveau driver with the nvidia driver. Now the problems are completely gone.

I guess I now need to read up on how to make sure that nvidia won't drain my battery...

If anybody knows any better methods that don't involve a nonfree driver, let me know.