# Battery goes down to 0% on gnome3

Tags: gnome, power-management, ubuntu-gnome

Recenly I started experimenting with Ubuntu on my laptop (HP Pavilion X360). I chose the newest Ubuntu Gnome, because it's my favourite desktop environment. It looks really great for me, but there are some issues.

I left my laptop powered on few times. There are no "critical battery status" power options in my settings. But I think it should not recovering journal and start from 1% after plugging in to the wall.

What can I do to force my computer to hibernate or power off if battery is at, for example, 10%?

Thanks!

---

Excuse me, I do not think that my question is duplicate, as marked by moderator. My question is about making computer to perform ANY action and not let battery go to complete zero. And linked question is about changing behavior - sleep instead of shutdown.

My computer does not even shutdown. Does not hibernate. Just goes out of power and turns off.

Comment: Have you even tried the solutions in that answer?  because what you describe in your original question has ***the exact same solution*** as the other problem.

Comment: If your computer doesn't behave as programmed when power is critically low, It might be useful to [sanity check your ACPI table](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939764/how-do-i-sanity-check-my-acpi-tables/939765#939765 )

Comment: There are several versions of the x360. It might be useful to know which one you are talking about. Thank you for helping us help you!